# Can I upgrade Ubuntu by installing latest version over the older?

Tags: upgrade

I have Ubuntu 11.04 on my laptop , and I want to upgrade it to Ubuntu 12.04. I have tried to upgrade from upgrade manager but based on my home internet speed , it estimated around 48 hrs so I quit it .

More over I have Ubuntu 12.04 installable , So I wanted to ask what will happen to my 11.04 if I install 12.04 over it , will my data of 11.04 will be lost ?

How will I achieve the upgrade?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I upgrade from 10.04 or 11.10 to 12.04?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-from-10-04-or-11-10-to-12-04)

Answer (score 0):

You will need the [alternate cd](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/) to upgrade to 12.04 when you don't want to install over the network.

I know 12.10 doesn't use an alternate install disc anymore, so i assume the primary install disc works as an upgrade without network access.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading will not delete your private data or the programs you have installed in 11.04. Further warning: new desktop versions tend to mangle old desktop config files. check this which will show you how to upgrade using various ways [How do I upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-from-10-04-or-11-10-to-12-04)